# Automatically assign method arguments like Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter, parameters from the URI are automatically made available to the method being called.

For example:

`/admin/edit/news/1` in the url would mean that in the `admin` controller, you could do the following:

```
function edit($table,$id)
{
    echo $table; // outputs 'news'
    echo $id; // outputs '1'
}
```

So, in essence you are able to name and use the arguments within the method without previously having 'passed them in' in that order anywhere, and regardless of how many there are, they are still passed to the function in the order they appear in the URI.

I guess this must have something to do with the `__call()` magic method, but I can't get my head around how to pass them to the method being called as though they were individual arguments and not an `$args` array as received by the `__call()` method.

How is this achieved?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: Thanks Steve. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the inteire logic around this magic on `system/core/CodeIgniter.php` file.

You can see how it is instantiating the class 
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/CodeIgniter.php#L500

And also, I highlighted the line that is doing the job of call the method with parameters.

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/CodeIgniter.php#L514

[]'s